# Group by day and then again group by user to get list of object or object's id

Tags: django, django-2.0

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booked_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    bought = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I would like to group tickets by booked day, and then again group each day's ticket list by ticket's user (admin / customer) i.e., user is_admin or not, finally to get list of ticket or ticket's id.

```
[
    {
        'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 6, 0, 0, ...), 
        'booked_by_admin': [1, 2, 5],
        'booked_by_customer': [3, 4]
    }, 
    {
        'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 7, 0, 0, ...), 
        'booked_by_admin': [11, 12, 16],
        'booked_by_customer': [10, 13, 14, 15]
    }
]
```

I could group tickets by day this way,

```
Ticket.objects.filter(bought=True).annotate(day=TruncDay('booked_at')).values('day').annotate(c=Count('id')).order_by()
```

But I cannot figure out how to again group it by admin user and non admin user to get list of ticket objects. Could you help me please.

Comment: did u trie add `.order_by('user__is_admin')` at the end of your query? where *user__is_admin* - field of your related `user` model.

Comment: @Chiefir Ok, `.order_by('user__is_admin')` does help a bit by separating the results in to two. But there is no way to tell if its of admin or non admin. Also how can I return list of object or object's id.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by module, may be this is what u need. It looks like Django does not have that functionality at the moment what u need.

Comment: @Chiefir Yes, I was just looking into that.